# How to delay embedding of javascript?

Tags: javascript, embed

I'm embedding a Google trends widget in the sidebar of my site which delays the loading of the whole page. And also, sometimes the script never stops loading which almost cause my browser to crash. The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fig%2Fmodules%2Fgoogle_insightsforsearch_relatedsearches.xml&amp;up__results_type=RISING&amp;up__property=empty&amp;up__search_term=&amp;up__location=SE&amp;up__category=0&amp;up__time_range=1-m&amp;up__max_results=10&amp;synd=open&amp;w=252&amp;h=350&amp;lang=sv&amp;title=Google+Trender&amp;border=0&amp;output=js"></script>
```

It simply returns markup that I cannot change and as far as I understand I can't put this script in the footer of my site and then have an html element higher up on the site which is replaced after the script is loaded. How can I delay loding of this script?

Comment: `I can't put this script in the footer of my site` Why's that then?

Comment: Cause then the widget markup is added to the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, I will assume that your script is currently somewhere in the middle of your page like this...

```
<div id="widget">
    <script src="google..."></script>
</div>
```

... and also that the script essentially dumps out content to wherever it happens to be placed, which precludes you from moving it to the end of your document.

You could add the script element later like this...

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="widget">
    </div>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var widgetScript = document.createElement('script')
        widgetScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
        widgetScript.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fig%2Fmodules%2Fgoogle_insightsforsearch_relatedsearches.xml&amp;up__results_type=RISING&amp;up__property=empty&amp;up__search_term=&amp;up__location=SE&amp;up__category=0&amp;up__time_range=1-m&amp;up__max_results=10&amp;synd=open&amp;w=252&amp;h=350&amp;lang=sv&amp;title=Google+Trender&amp;border=0&amp;output=js')
        document.getElementById('widget').appendChild(widgetScript);
    </script>
</body>
```

So the script that loads the widget script is right at the bottom of your page, so it will only run once your DOM is pretty much ready. It then creates the script tag and adds it to the element you want it in.

**UPDATE** - based on your feedback using this method, this alternative may help, although it is a bit "gnarly".

Here is an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/QCmb2/). Note that the page is visible even though the widget is actually still loading.

This works by loading a script into a hidden div at the very bottom of the page, and then when it loads, shifting the contents of the hidden div into the visible widget div that is further up in the page flow.

Comment: This looks great but it isn't working, the script isn't loading. Maybe it's because the script is returning markup; a table and some CSS.

Comment: @RichardB - I have added a JSFiddle that shows an alternate method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to load the script asynchronously:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="true" src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fig%2Fmodules%2Fgoogle_insightsforsearch_relatedsearches.xml&amp;up__results_type=RISING&amp;up__property=empty&amp;up__search_term=&amp;up__location=SE&amp;up__category=0&amp;up__time_range=1-m&amp;up__max_results=10&amp;synd=open&amp;w=252&amp;h=350&amp;lang=sv&amp;title=Google+Trender&amp;border=0&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Comment: If the request URL is wrong It wont load, but to load a script asyncrhonously as you requested thats the proper way to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks, the script is correct though. Maybe it's something in the script that makes it impossible to load asynchronously, I got it from here: http://www.google.com/insights/search/#cmpt=q

Comment: It is entirely possible that something in the code you are including won't work in this way. I will add an alternative, which is more fiddly, but may help.